# How can I request focus on a text field as soon as FXML loads?

Tags: javafx, focus, textfield, fxml, setfocus

I am creating a JavaFX application using FXML. In this application I have a button that loads a FXML scene in a portion of the Stage, like loading a FXML file as a child of another FXML scene. I want to request focus on a text field so I can type as soon as the child scene loads, without having to manually click the text field with the mouse. I tried using `textField.requestFocus()` in the `initialize()` method of my controller class, but nothing happens. I read it is because the text field is not yet visible when the method is run, so it cannot have focus. I also tried using `textField.requestFocus()` on the button's action handler, after the new scene is added, but for this I had to make the TextField public and static to be accessed outside the controller class. This approach seemed to partially work as the textfield's prompt text disappeared, but I still cannot type inside it without clicking with the mouse. After that, I tried adding a ChangeListener to the textfield's visibleProperty and used:

```
if(textField.isVisible()) textField.requestFocus();
```

But this also did nothing.
Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Code for the main scene:

```
    //The controller class for the FXML containing the button that is pressed to go to the FXML with the TextField
public class StartScene {
    @FXML
    BorderPane contentPane; //Where the other fxml file will be loaded
    private String path = "../fxml/fxmlFile.fxml";
    private static Parent component = null;
    @FXML
    private void initialize() throws IOException {

        component = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path));
    }
    @FXML
    //This method is set to the onAction of a button
    private void loadComponent(){
        if (!contentPane.getChildren().contains(component)) {
            contentPane.getChildren().clear();
            contentPane.setCenter(component);
        }
        else { System.out.println("Component already inserted"); }
     }
}
```

Code for the controller of scene with textfield

```
public class TextFieldSceneController {
    @FXML
    TextField textField;
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        textField.setPromptText("Prompt");
    }
}
```

FXML for StartScene:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane minHeight="500" minWidth="900" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
       fx:controller="StartScene" >
    <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane">
        <left>
            <VBox minHeight="500" prefWidth="250" minWidth="10">
                    <Button text="BUTTON" minHeight="30" minWidth="100" prefWidth="250"  alignment="CENTER" onAction="#loadComponent"/>
             </VBox>
        </left>
        <center>
            <BorderPane minWidth="600" minHeight="500" fx:id="contentPane">
                 <children>
                 </children>
            </BorderPane>
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
</StackPane>
```

FXML for Scene with TextField:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?> 

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
       fx:controller="TextFieldSceneController" prefHeight="600.0" maxWidth="800.0" fx:id="root">
    <VBox fx:id="base">
        <children>
            <TextField fx:id="textField" alignment="CENTER"/>
        </children>
    </VBox>
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

First of all, you are loading your `component` before you actually need it. This means that the `initialize()` method has been called and finished running long before you actually show the `component` in your `BorderPane`.

Instead, you should load the `FXML` document only once the button has been clicked (move the loading to your `loadComponent()` method).

Then, you may add this to your `initialize()` method of your `TextFieldSceneController` class:

`Platform.runLater(() -> textField.requestFocus());`

Calling `Platform.runLater()` will schedule your `TextField` to gain focus "at some unspecified time in the future."  In this case, it would execute after the `Scene` has been loaded and rendered.

> You can learn more about `Platform.runLater()` by reading the [JavaFX documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: Tried this, also no look :/ . The textfield must still be clicked to type inside it

Comment: Please update your question and include a [mcve] then. I suspect there may be other factors involved.

Comment: Please take a look once more, I added the code for the controller classes but not the FXML as I assume that wouldn't matter much

Comment: Please read the link I posted for a [mcve]. The point there is to provide enough code that I can actually copy and run as-is to see where the problem lies.

Comment: I am sorry. FXML is added

Comment: Never mind, after loading the fxml document inside the loadComponent() method, it is working as intended. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use a common superclass for view controllers (it is part of a framework I wrote for declaratively loading and injecting the view/controller tuples into other managed beans using an IoC container but that is not required to solve this problem).

In the ViewController superclass I created lifecycle callback methods for subclasses to override which are called by the superclass implementation in response to changes in observed properties of the view. Here is the relevant bit...

```
public abstract class ViewController<V extends Parent> {

  private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<V> view = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(this, "view");

  protected ViewController() {
    viewProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      if (newValue != null) {
        viewDidLoad(newValue);
      }
    });
  }

  public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<V> viewProperty() {
    return view.getReadOnlyProperty();
  }

  void setView(V view) {
    this.view.set(view);
  }

  public V getView() {
    return viewProperty().get();
  }

  protected void viewDidChangeScene(Scene oldScene, Scene newScene) {}

  protected void viewDidLoad(V view) {
    view.sceneProperty().addListener((o, oldScene, newScene) -> this.viewDidChangeScene(oldScene, newScene));
  }

}
```

In a subclass where I want to ensure a text field receives focus on load I add ...

```
@Override
protected void viewDidChangeScene(Scene oldScene, Scene newScene) {
  usernameField.requestFocus();
}
```